# Why my Favicon icon doesn't appear when I run the view in the browser from Dreamweaver editor?

Tags: html, favicon

this is my HTML code:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="StaticPictures/MyFavicon.ico" />
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**also:

1. I tried to add from website root.
2. My icon 16X16 pixels.
3. I cleaned cache from web browser.
4. I Tried to load page with (Explorer , Edge , Chrome) but without success.
5. I tried to convert icon to (PNG or GIF) and use this code:**

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I realized that the problem was only in Dreamweaver editor because run html file or from another editor works well.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. You should be able to solve it by adding the following code to your javascript file:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.type = 'image/x-icon';
link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
link.href = 'StaticPictures/MyFavicon.ico'
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that both the HTML5 specification of W3C and WhatWG standardize,
try this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/StaticPictures/MyFavicon.ico" />
```

Here is something that you might like: https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon